EtherCAT unable to initialize using dll
I'm trying to connect a device using EtherCAT protocol. My setup contains master (main pc) and slave (temperature sensor device). I have an EC Engr and EC STA as dongle for Acontis. Both EC-Engineer and TwinCAT shell works fine but my code stuck on initialize.
btw, I'm using Acontis_EtherCAT_Driver.dll.
public static Acontis_EtherCAT acontis = new Acontis_EtherCAT(null);
public static void Init()
    {
        acontis.ENI_File = @"C:\...\eniFile.xml";
        acontis.StateChangeTimeout = 15000;
        acontis.MasterCycleTime = 4000;
        try
        {
            if (acontis.EtherCAT_Master_Initialize() == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }

Error:

Sequence contains no elements

